# Why are my form fields getting set to empty when I submit my Rails 5 form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, submit, ruby-on-rails-5

I’m using Rails 5.  I have the following model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z/
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create

  before_save :encrypt_password
  after_save :clear_password

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.encrypted_password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
    end
  end
  def clear_password
    self.password = nil
end

end
```

and here is how I save that information after receiving it in the controller …

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation))
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
```

but when I submit my form, although you can see from the logs below that there are values for “email” and “username,” for some reason, those are getting wiped out when I try and seve things …

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-06 10:45:39 -0600
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"btf3ceTkB51g65p7vl1aFkLS+vKun9Xdl3PPW9fSbcNsJn/4jk8fo1ekis8d4Foc7lzmeEITwfjdkos07ndZ5g==", "user"=>{"username"=>"myemail", "email"=>"myemail@msn.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Signup"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["username", "myemail"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "myemail@msn.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (3.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("encrypted_password", "salt", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$h6V6zoZOrPmurBWfoAuzwOcOXurYWc6aqLmgL1Z0wD7V1qhfRywRy"], ["salt", "$2a$10$h6V6zoZOrPmurBWfoAuzwO"], ["created_at", 2016-12-06 16:45:39 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-12-06 16:45:39 UTC]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 104ms (ActiveRecord: 12.7ms)
```

How do I preserve the values of the fields that are submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove this line. Sure all these fields existed in the table

```
attr_accessor :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Comment: Gave that a go but then got the error "unknown attribute 'password' for User." on the line "@user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)) "

Comment: Oh taht's b/c I don't hae a db column named "password".  Changing the line to "attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation" works.